# warning and error in sphinxsearch indexer

Tags: search-engine, sphinx

I want to know the list of possible errors and warnings that may occur in `sphinxsearch` indexer.
I couldn't find this list in internet.
If anyone knows, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found warning and error in this [link](https://github.com/sphinxsearch/sphinx/blob/master/src/indexer.cpp) .
Just search the word ‍‍**warning** or **error** in the file `indexer.cpp`.